# Filtering rows with junk characters using SQL Server regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

In my table, certain rows have junk characters like Ё㺞稹㾸䐶ꖆ㩜癈ῤ in certain columns. I am trying to filter out such rows like below:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 NOT LIKE '%[REGEX]%'
```

1. Is there any better approach?
2. If no, how can I generate a proper regex? I don't want any records where Col2 has anything but alphanumeric characters, punctuations, and a space.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any decent Regex support out of the box; you could extend it using a SQL CLR assembly, but T-SQL itself has **very limited** regex support...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support proper RegExs in the `LIKE`.

The pattern syntax does support negation (`^`) and ranges or sets of characters though so you could use something like..

```
WHERE Col2  LIKE N'%[^0-9A-Za-z .,;:]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: OK, I tried the following expression:    N'%[^0-9A-Za-z `~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:"'',<.>/?]%'     

But it returns 0 records out for ~25,000 records. Obvuiously, I am doing something wrong. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You have `)-_` in there, SQL Server will treat that as a range. Put the `-` right on the end. Also I wonder if `_` needs to be escaped as that has particular significance in like patterns.

Comment: Still no luck.This is what I tried: [^0-9A-Za-z `~!@#$%^&*()_=+[{]}\|;:"'',<.>/?-]

Comment: @Ruby - Also you have `]` in there which SQL Server will interpret as closing the negated expression and `%` and `_` may well cause problems as well. You could probably use `ESCAPE` to get around this but much simpler to use `WHERE Col2 LIKE N'%[^ -~]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN` as you seem to be looking for all strings containing characters not between ASCII 32 and 126 inclusive. The `collate` clause is important here.

Comment: FYI: This will not capture NULL-Terminated data.  Spent a few hours tracking down the ASCII value 0x00 (zero), which represents a NULL Character value.  Took forever to find it because it wouldn't show up in results or using this filter, but it sure would break my conversion to XML.